# CMake install: Preserve file timestamps

Tags: cmake

In my git repo, I am copying some files to the target.

`install(DIRECTORY data/ DESTINATION usr/bin)`

However, I want to preserve the file timestamps (last_updated). There is an option to set a timestamp, but I can't find one to preserve it. Any suggestions on how to preserve a file's timestamp?